# After update to highcharts.js today we get Highcharts.chart is not a constructor

Tags: highcharts

We pull in highcharts.js, modules/annotations.js, and modules/exporting.js.
Our charts were working fine yesterday, but are broken today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Highcharts v11.0.0 has been released and you are using the newest version now.

As you can see in the changelog, one of the new features is:

- Changed the default builds to ECMAScript version ES2016.

That's mean that you can no longer use the `new Highcharts.chart()` notation. To create a chart, use:

```
Highcharts.chart([renderTo], options [, callback]);
```

or

```
new Highcharts.Chart([renderTo], options [, callback]);
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#Chart

**Changelog:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v11.0.0

Comment: Thanks so much. We've pinned to `https://code.highcharts.com/10.0.0/highcharts.js for now.`

Comment: Sorry, what am I missing here? What is the difference?

Comment: Hi @JamesG, The difference is in the size of the char `c`. `Highcharts.chart` is a function and `Highcharts.Chart` is a class.

Comment: Started working back on my old project and faced this error. Thanks for pointing out the error and everything is running smooth now.